# How to do I output SeriLog json properties onto a .txt format

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

**Reference**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iryZxv8Rxw&t=2105s&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey (44:00) 
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment C# SeriLog outputTemplate formatting

**What I Want**
I want to the property SourceContext seen in the video to be displayed onto my .txt output
but the problem is the video does it in a Json file, and I am unsure of how to apply it to 
a C# and .txt context.

**What I Have**
Nothing much, just the basics. I would like to know what I am missing to get its output.

```
#region Logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.WithProcessId()
            .Enrich.WithProcessName()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt",
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose,
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Exception:1}{NewLine}")
            .CreateLogger();
            Log.Verbose("Test Verbose");
            Log.Debug("Test Debug.");
            Log.Information("Test Info.");
            Log.Warning("Test Warning!");
            Log.Error("Test Error!!");
            Log.Fatal("Test Fatal!!");
            #endregion
```

Answer (score 2):

You [control event formatting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#controlling-event-formatting) either by specifying an output template string (as per your example) or by providing a custom `ITextFormatter` that does the formatting (example shown in the video you linked).

In your example, you can simply include `SourceContext` in the output template:

```
"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

If you want all properties present in the log event (which would include `SourceContext`) you can use `{Properties}` instead:

```
"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Properties} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

Comment: I did try it out, but it does not come out on .txt, only .json.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want it in a C# context. Note that multi-threading may be a consequent issue.

https://gist.github.com/litetex/b88fe0531e5acea82df1189643fb1f79